# How to turn a group of individuals into dyads using R?

Tags: r

[For example, I have a group of 5 people playing together. They were observed on day 1 and all belong to group 1. (The format is illustrated in picture 1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5TyRm.png)

[Now I want to turn them from individual subjects into different dyads. The possible outcome format is shown in picture 2.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2qyfd.png)

Please can anyone help me how to code this in R? I am desperate for some help.

Comment: Please provide data as text, not images.

Comment: Please add data using `dput` and not as images. Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 1):

You really need to add reproducible sample data via `dput()` so we can help with exact code. But the gist of it is the following work flow:

```r
library(dplyr)
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(group_member = paste(id,collapse = "_")) %>%
  separate(group_member,into = c("g1","g2","g3","g4"),sep = "_") %>%
  gather(id1,id2,-id,-group,-activity,-day) %>%
  mutate(id1 = id)
```